# Django: getting m2m values after model_save

Tags: django, django-admin

I have run into an issue trying to get m2m field values after model_save in admin:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    relation = models.ManyToManyField(MyRelatedModel, blank=False, null=False)
    ...

class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    ...

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        super(MyModelAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)

        for rel in obj.relation.all():
            # Code here is not executed on first (initial) save - why?
            ...
```

The code above works on 2nd and following saves of the instance, but not on the initial one. Shouldn't it be working since I already called super on MyModelAdmin.save_model or is there something else I'm missing and m2m is saved separately somehow?

Comment: After `super` try invoking `form.save_m2m()`

Comment: Posted as an answer also :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After `super` method invoke `form.save_m2m()`:

```
class MyModelAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):

    ...

    def save_model(self, request, obj, form, change):
        super(MyModelAdmin, self).save_model(request, obj, form, change)
        form.save_m2m()
```